# Proper way to disable tmpfs on /run/shm

Tags: debian, tmpfs

How do I disable `tmpfs` on `/run/shm`? I searched through initscripts and found that the following code checks the entry in `fstab`, but what should I change to make it not mount `/run/shm`? I'm running Debian sid.

#### /lib/init/mount-functions.sh

```
read_fstab_entry () {
        # Not found by default.
        found=1

        for file in "$(eval ls $(fstab_files))"; do
                if [ -f "$file" ]; then
                        while read MNT_FSNAME MNT_DIR MNT_TYPE MNT_OPTS MNT_FREQ MNT_PASS MNT_JUNK; do
                                case "$MNT_FSNAME" in
                                  ""|\#*)
                                        continue;
                                        ;;
                                esac
                                if [ "$MNT_DIR" = "$1" ]; then
                                        if [ -n "$2" ]; then
                                                [ "$MNT_TYPE" = "$2" ] || continue;
                                        fi
                                        found=0
                                        break 2
                                fi
                        done < "$file"
                fi
        done

        return $found
```

#### Function callsite

```
 if read_fstab_entry /run/lock; then
            if [ "$MNT_TYPE" = "tmpfs" ] ; then
                RAMLOCK="yes"
            else
                RAMLOCK="no"
            fi
        fi
```

#### Later

```
if [ yes = "$RAMLOCK" ]; then
                domount "$MNTMODE" tmpfs shmfs /run/lock tmpfs "-o${NODEV}noexec,nosuid$LOCK_OPT"
                # Make sure we don't get cleaned
                touch /run/lock/.tmpfs
        else
                chmod "$LOCK_MODE" /run/lock
        fi
```

Answer (score 2):

It's not clear what you're trying to achieve. By default (at least on Debian wheezy), `/run/shm` is a subdirectory of `/run`, which is mounted as tmpfs. So if you don't want `/run/shm` to be a mount point, don't change the default configuration. If you create an entry for `/run/shm` in `/etc/fstab`, it will be mounted only if you specify the filesystem type; otherwise `/dev/shm` is bind-mounted there. Not having `/run/shm` as tmpfs is not a supported configuration. If you want to use some other filesystem type, create an fstab entry and edit `/etc/init.d/mountall.sh` and `/etc/init.d/mountdevsubfs.sh` so that they call `mount_shm` with an argument other than `mount` or `mount_update`. Whatever you do, make sure that `/run/shm` is mode 1777 and has no files left over from a previous boot.

Comment: I want /run/shm not mounted, run also as well, because tmpfs slowdown system.

Comment: The slowdown case [here](http://superuser.com/questions/503293/how-to-tell-chrome-not-use-run-shm-or-how-to-make-run-shm-not-mounted-as-tmpfs)

Answer (score 1):

Put `#` in front of the fstab-Entry, to mark it as a comment.

If you look at the script that will trigger the `continue`-branch within the `case`-statement, making it skip that line.

Comment: there is no fstab entry here.

Comment: @eicto There has to be a file with an entry for "/run/lock" in one of the files denoted by **fstab_files**. Can you locate the place, where fstab_files is allocated a value?

Comment: I solved the problem, just installed 16G  to  workstation.

Answer (score 0):

Read the comments on `/etc/default/tmpfs`, edit the file (add `RAMSHM=no`), save and reboot.

Comment: no such file bro